# PostgreSQL Percentage of mobile/web users

Tags: postgresql

There are two tables. One table has all mobile actions (all pages visited by the users on mobile). The other table has all web actions (all pages visited on web by the users). I am trying to return the percentage of users who only visited mobile, only web, and both. That is, the percentage of users who are only in the mobile table, only in the web table and in both tables. The sum of the percentages should return 1. I am struggling to figure out why my solution is incorrect. Here is the [dataset](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://drive.google.com/uc?export%3Ddownload%26id%3D0B5G7QmUBc4IRZmJabU5OWDM0MTg&sa=D&ust=1619650153424000&usg=AOvVaw1iYQnWDjPY_nMTDAZ4WQx7&hl=en) if needed. Thanks in advance.

mobile_table

- user_id (id of the user who visited a given page on mobile, ex: 128)
- page (page visited by that user on mobile, ex: page_5_mobile)

web_table

- user_id (id of the user who visited a given page on web, ex: 1210)
- page (page visited by that user on web, ex: page_1_web)

Here's my attempted solution:

```
with t1 as
(select count(*) as t1_count
from mobile_table),

t2 as
(select count(*) as t2_count
from web_table),

t3 as 
(select count(*) as t3_count
from web_table
join mobile_table 
on q2_web.user_id = q2_mobile.user_id)

select round(cast(t1_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count+ t3_count),2) as mobile_usage,
round(cast(t2_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count+t3_count),2) as web_usage,
round(cast(t3_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count+t3_count),2) as mobile_and_web_usage
from t1, t2, t3
```

The outcome of my query:

- mobile_usage: 37.06
- web_usage: 25.14
- mobile_and_web_usage: 37.80

The only issue is that the official solution is different:

- mobile_usage: 16
- web_usage: 31
- mobile_and_web_usage: 52

Comment: do you have seperate user table also?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra, I only have 2 tables (mobile_table, web_table)  which I posted above.

Comment: no issue, you can follow the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are adding `t3_count`. it should be subtracted.

Try this way

```
with t1 as
(select count(distinct user_id) as t1_count
from mobile_table),

t2 as
(select count(distinct user_id) as t2_count
from web_table),

t3 as 
(select count(distinct q2_web.user_id) as t3_count
from web_table q2_web
join mobile_table q2_mobile
on q2_web.user_id = q2_mobile.user_id)

select round(cast(t1_count-t3_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count- t3_count),0) as mobile_usage,
round(cast(t2_count-t3_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count-t3_count),0) as web_usage,
round(cast(t3_count as numeric)*100/(t1_count+t2_count-t3_count),0) as mobile_and_web_usage
from t1, t2, t3
```

In more shorter way you can write your query like below:

```
with ct as(
select 
coalesce(t1.user_id,t2.user_id),
count(t1.page) "mobile",count(t2.page) "web" from mobile_table t1 full outer join web_table t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
group by 1)
select 
round(cast(count(*) filter (where mobile>0 and web=0) as numeric)/count(*),2)*100 "Mobile",
round(cast(count(*) filter (where mobile=0 and web>0) as numeric)/count(*),2)*100 "WEB",
round(cast(count(*) filter (where mobile>0 and web>0) as numeric)/count(*),2)*100 "BOTH"
from ct
```

Comment: I tried your 1st answer but for some reason I am not getting the expected outcome as the official solution. Official solution is (mobile_usage: 16, web_usage: 31, mobile_and_web_usage: 52). Running your first query I get (mobile_usage: -1.18, web_usage: -20.34, mobile_and_web_usage: 60.76).

Comment: Corrected the first query. now you can check but second query was already correct